# How can I implement VGG-net on a dataset of different shape?

Tags: keras, vgg-net

I am trying to use a part of the VGG16 model for transfer learning using the Fashion MNIST dataset. The data is processed and the model is specified as per below:

```
    data = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
    (train_img, train_labels), (test_img, test_labels) = data.load_data()

    train_img.shape, train_labels.shape, test_img.shape, test_labels.shape
    #((60000, 28, 28), (60000,), (10000, 28, 28), (10000,))

    # transform to rgb as required by VGG
    train_img=tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb(tf.expand_dims(train_img, axis=3)) 
    test_img=tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb(tf.expand_dims(test_img, axis=3))

    #resize to minimum size of (32x32
    train_img=tf.image.resize_with_pad(train_img,32,32)
    test_img=tf.image.resize_with_pad(train_img,32,32)

    train_img = train_img / 255.
    test_img = test_img / 255.

    from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
    train_img = tf.expand_dims(train_img, axis=0)
    test_img = tf.expand_dims(test_img, axis=0)

    #preprocessing as required by VGG16
    train_img=preprocess_input(train_img)
    test_img=preprocess_input(test_img)

    #using model without last layers
    vgg16=tf.keras.applications.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(32,32,3))

    layer_dict = dict([(layer.name, layer) for layer in vgg16.layers])
    #stop at block3_pool and get output
    output = layer_dict['block3_pool'].output

    x = keras.layers.Flatten()(output)
    ...add some fully connected layers  here...
    x = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)

    final = keras.models.Model(inputs=vgg16.input, outputs=model)
    for layer in final.layers[:7]:
    layer.trainable = False

    final.fit(train_img, train_labels, epochs=50, validation_split=0.2)
```

When I try to fit the model I get the following error:

```
   UnboundLocalError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-6a0b99b56337> in <module>()
      1 early_stopping_cb=keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=3, verbose=1,restore_best_weights=True)
----> 2 vgg16_1.fit(train_img, train_labels, epochs=50, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[early_stopping_cb])

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    857               logs = tmp_logs  # No error, now safe to assign to logs.
    858               callbacks.on_train_batch_end(step, logs)
--> 859         epoch_logs = copy.copy(logs)
    860 
    861         # Run validation.

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'logs' referenced before assignment
```

I thought this might be due to the training set shape being faulty, but then if I use train_img[0] instead, which has shape (60000,32,32,3), then I get the following error instead:

```
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-2b893ccd9ac9> in <module>()
      1 early_stopping_cb=keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=3, verbose=1,restore_best_weights=True)
----> 2 vgg16_1.fit(train_img[0], train_labels, epochs=50, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[early_stopping_cb])

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
     64   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
     65     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
---> 66       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
     67 
     68     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    849                 batch_size=batch_size):
    850               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
--> 851               tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
    852               # Catch OutOfRangeError for Datasets of unknown size.
    853               # This blocks until the batch has finished executing.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    578         xla_context.Exit()
    579     else:
--> 580       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    581 
    582     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    625       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    626       initializers = []
--> 627       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    628     finally:
    629       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    504     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    505         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 506             *args, **kwds))
    507 
    508     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2444       args, kwargs = None, None
   2445     with self._lock:
-> 2446       graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2447     return graph_function
   2448 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   2775 
   2776       self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 2777       graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   2778       self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   2779       return graph_function, args, kwargs

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   2665             arg_names=arg_names,
   2666             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 2667             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   2668         self._function_attributes,
   2669         # Tell the ConcreteFunction to clean up its graph once it goes out of

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    979         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    980 
--> 981       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    982 
    983       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    439         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    440         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 441         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    442     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    443 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    966           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    967             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 968               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    969             else:
    970               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:571 train_function  *
        outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:951 run  **
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2290 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2649 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:533 train_step  **
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:204 __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:143 __call__
        losses = self.call(y_true, y_pred)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:246 call
        return self.fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:1527 categorical_crossentropy
        return K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py:4561 categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py:1117 assert_is_compatible_with
        raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

    ValueError: Shapes (32, 1) and (32, 10) are incompatible
```

Any clues where these errors come from and what I am doing wrong? It feels like I might have missed something obvious, but being a Keras novice I can't get my head around what it is. Help much appreciated.

Comment: The first error you have listed is due to the callback function you are providing. Your model might have no problem. The callback function has some undeclared variable called 'logs' that you are trying to use. Try running it without the callback function, if it works, fix your callback function. (You have not listed your callback function, so I cannot point out the specific error)

Comment: Thanks, the callback I use is early stopping, but removing it doesn't change the errors I get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the issue was that I had a dense output layer of size 10, while the labels have size 1. Solution was to use sparse categorical cross-entropy loss function instead of simple categorical.

Answer (score 1):

You need to comment two lines on expanding dims as follows. What happens is that it updates the shape of `train_img` to (1,60000,32,32,3) and `model.fit` complains that you are using single image for training.

```
#train_img = tf.expand_dims(train_img, axis=0)
#test_img = tf.expand_dims(test_img, axis=0)
```

I updated your code and shared [Here](https://github.com/jvishnuvardhan/Stackoverflow_Questions/blob/master/Untitled114.ipynb). You need to update the architecture to improve it for better accuracy. Follow transfer learning approach mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning) and update your code for better accuacy. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, expand_dims was indeed part of the problem.